# Unit8Array to base64 conversion and then displaying image in browser issue

Tags: javascript, image, mongodb, meteor

I have a Unit8Array in a mongodb that represents a png image. I pull the array out and convert it to base64 using javascript (in meteor client side) so that I can display it in the browser. The code is as follows

```
var blob = new Uint8Array(Tester.findOne().image);
var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, blob));
var src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64String + '';
console.log(src);
```

Where Tester.findOne().image is my mongodb collection containing the Uint8Array. 
I take the src once it is logged and I paste it into the browser. The generic broken image icon appears (see below). However when I click the broken image in the browser and say save to desktop, it downloads the file and when I open it the png image appears as expected.

[image: Broken Image]

After I Download the Image:
[image: Saving Image]
[image]
When I directly try to assign it to `<img src = 'data'>`:
[image]
Adding data as img source or by using document.findElementbyId("img") then changing img.src:
[image]

Comment: any reason the image is being stored in MongoDB? it's recommended that you use something else such as Amazon S3 to store images and keep them out of Mongo

Comment: @flylib yeah i'm working with meteor (http://docs.meteor.com/#top)

Comment: yeah but you can still use something other then mongo to store the images when working with meteor, such as a folder on your server or a bucket on s3 if you configure it properly, documents in mongodb can only be max 16mb

Comment: @flylib what I have resorted too is using a mongo objective-c driver from an mac app to insert my file into gridfs (mongodb file manager for files larger than 16mb). I want to pull out that file out into my meteor app. I am using collectionfs (https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) to store files in the meteor app but it cannot pull out the file using collectionfs.